# TelephonyDevController not yet created?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, требуется помощь профессионала, так как эта задача чрезвычайно сложна.

Пытаюсь создать экземпляр класса `com.android.internal.telephony.RIL`. Закрытый API я добавил и **все сделал правильно** - фреймворк модема пропустил через dex2jar и добавил в используемые классы. Также открыл `jar` в `jd-gui`. Кстати, скорее всего фреймворк был модифицирован производетелем - `Micromax`. Вызвал статический метод `TelephonyDevController.getModemCount()` и получил возвращаемое значение - **все работает**. Вообще задача следующая:

Существует интерфейс `com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard` с методом `boolean getIccLockEnabled()`. Существует класс, его реализующий - `com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardProxy`. Я хочу вызвать его метод `getIccLockEnabled`. Чтобы создать экземпляр этого классa, в его конструктор требуется передать параметры `android.content.Context`, `com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface` и `int`. Второй параметр является интерфейсом, а значит можно передать его сабкласс, а именно, `com.android.internal.telephony.RIL`. Чтобы создать экземпляр `RIL`, в его конструктор требуется передать контекст и два `int`. Но вот при создании `RIL`-а приложение вылетает с логом `TelephonyDevController not yet created!?!`.

Вот конструктор классa `RIL`

```
    public RIL(Context paramContext, int paramInt1, int paramInt2, Integer paramInteger)
  {
    super(paramContext);
    riljLog("RIL(context, preferredNetworkType=" + paramInt1 + " cdmaSubscription=" + paramInt2 + ")");
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    this.mCdmaSubscription = paramInt2;
    this.mPreferredNetworkType = paramInt1;
    this.mPhoneType = 0;
    this.mInstanceId = paramInteger;
    this.mWakeLock = ((PowerManager)paramContext.getSystemService("power")).newWakeLock(1, "RILJ");
    this.mWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
    this.mWakeLockTimeout = SystemProperties.getInt("ro.ril.wake_lock_timeout", 60000);
    this.mWakeLockCount = 0;
    this.mSenderThread = new HandlerThread("RILSender" + this.mInstanceId);
    this.mSenderThread.start();
    this.mSender = new RILSender(this.mSenderThread.getLooper());
    if (!((ConnectivityManager)paramContext.getSystemService("connectivity")).isNetworkSupported(0)) {
      riljLog("Not starting RILReceiver: wifi-only");
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      TelephonyDevController.getInstance();
      TelephonyDevController.registerRIL(this);
      return;
      riljLog("Starting RILReceiver" + this.mInstanceId);
      this.mReceiver = createRILReceiver();
      this.mReceiverThread = new Thread(this.mReceiver, "RILReceiver" + this.mInstanceId);
      this.mReceiverThread.start();
      paramContext = (DisplayManager)paramContext.getSystemService("display");
      this.mDefaultDisplay = paramContext.getDisplay(0);
      paramContext.registerDisplayListener(this.mDisplayListener, null);
    }
    }
```

И методы класса `TelephonyDevController` - `create()` и `getInstance()`

```
    public static TelephonyDevController create()
  {
    synchronized (mLock)
    {
      if (sTelephonyDevController != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("TelephonyDevController already created!?!");
      }
    }
    sTelephonyDevController = new TelephonyDevController();
    TelephonyDevController localTelephonyDevController = sTelephonyDevController;
    return localTelephonyDevController;
  }

  public static TelephonyDevController getInstance()
  {
    synchronized (mLock)
    {
      if (sTelephonyDevController == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("TelephonyDevController not yet created!?!");
      }
    }
    TelephonyDevController localTelephonyDevController = sTelephonyDevController;
    return localTelephonyDevController;
      }
```

Comment: А нельзя было просто взять исходники `TelephonyDevController` и `RIL` и просто тупо дуплицировать их у себя (в другом пакете) со всеми зависимыми импортами?

Comment: а вот сейчас не понял, это зачем?

Comment: Потому что это принятая практика когда вы хотите воспользоваться закрытыми/внутренними классами/API

Comment: Ну, уже поздно :) А что это мне даст?

Comment: Как версия у вас проблема в том, что внутренние классы где-то в недрах вызывают друг-друга или вы где-то что-то не инициализируете. Чтобы это понять, нужно выдернуть классы RIL и TelephonyDevController в свои пакеты и попробовать их собрать - сразу же увидите неразрешенные ссылки на другие классы/пакеты. У меня аналогичная история была с MMS - в итоге вынужден был вытянуть тучу исходников (что-то около 50 классов)

Comment: окей я сейчас попробую отпишусь

Comment: RIL перенес 1500 ошибок, огромный класс. Ему нужен импорт AsyncResult, android.os.Registrant, android.os.RegistrantList, android.os.SystemProperties, android.telephony.Rlog ;)) это точно нужно сделать?) что мне теперь дальше рыть фреймворки?

Comment: Сожалею, это как раз то из-за чего и происходит ошибка инициализации... Либо переносите, либо попробуйте через рефлексию - иногда это работает

Comment: jd-gui не до конца все сделал некоторый код покрыт знакми ???  и еще куча goto не пойму что за ошибки

Comment: @Barmaley, смотрите, я создал другой класс который наследуется от суперкласса `BaseCommands` передаются контекст в конструктор через `super(context)` и я вроде как создаю `IccCardProxy` но почему то все что я получаю имеет вид `false`, `null`, вы можете посмотреть код если я его добавлю ?